# If rank$(T)\le$rank$(T^3)$, then intersection of range and null space of $T$ is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $T:V\to V$ be linear trannsformation on a vector space $V$ with rank$(T)\le$ rank$(T^3)$. Then, what can be said about the null space and range of $T$. Typically, do they have empty intersection, or, is one the subset of another, or does there exist a subspace $W$ of $V$which equals their intersection.

I know that range of $T^3$ is a subspace of $T$ and null space of $T$ is a subspace of $T^3$. But, am unable to proceed further. Any hints. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: If the linear transformation has finite dimensional range, then this hypothesis says that $\Im(T) = \Im(T^3)$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

well first of all, lets consider $T$ as a linear map (this makes stuff in my opinion often a lot clearer). We know that $rank(T)=\dim \textrm{im}(T)$, But we know that $\text{im}(T^3)=\textrm{im}(T\mid_{\textrm{im}(T^2)})$, in particular $\textrm{im}T^3\subset \textrm{im} T$ but that just means in dimensions that $\dim \textrm{im}(T) \ge \dim \textrm{im}(T^3) $ in particular we get with your inequality $$\dim \textrm{im}(T) = \dim \textrm{im}(T^3)$$
But this just means that $T\mid_{\textrm{im}(T)}$ is an isomorphism. So $T\mid_{\textrm{im}(T)}$ has kernel zero. But this immediately gives $$0=\ker(T\mid_{\textrm{im}(T)}) = \ker(T)\cap \textrm{im}{T}$$

Comment: how does ranks being equal mean that the transformation is an isomorphism?

Comment: first of all, it is a linear map, second, it is not a rank, it is the dimension (as we are talking about spaces and not maps). Well, if the dimensions are equal, then the cardinality of your basis are the same. In particular (since the image of a basis is a generating set of the image) any image of a basis is linearly independent. but that just means that it is injective. now we get that the image is a subspace of another vector space with same finite dimension, hence they have to coincide, which gives surjectivity.

Comment: good explanation! so, if at any time, we have rank$(T)=rank(T^n)$, does that mean that the map is an isomorphism?

Comment: No! it means that it is an isomorphism if you restrict it to the image. a good example to keep in mind is a projection onto a subspace. But in general, maps like this will be the projection onto a subspace followed by a isomorphism on the subspace. 
a good exapmle is: $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 5):

Given that, $\operatorname{Rank}(T)\leq \operatorname{Rank}(T^3)\implies n-\operatorname{Rank}(T)\geq n-\operatorname{Rank}(T^3)$
By, Rank-nullity theorem
$$\operatorname N(T)\geq \operatorname N(T^3) \tag{1} \label{eqn1}$$
We know that,
$$\operatorname{Null space}\,(T)\subseteq \operatorname{Null space}\,(T^3) \tag{2} \label{eqn2}$$
$$\implies \operatorname N(T)\leq \operatorname N(T^3) \tag{3} \label{eqn3}$$
Now, from \eqref{eqn1} and \eqref{eqn3} we have
$$\operatorname N(T)=\operatorname N(T^3) \tag{4} \label{eqn4}$$
By \eqref{eqn2} and \eqref{eqn4} we have,
$$\operatorname{Null space}\,(T)=\operatorname{Null space}\,(T^3) \tag{5} \label{eqn5}$$
Now, let $x\in \operatorname{Null space} (T) \cap \operatorname{Range} (T)$ then, $T(x)=0$ and $\exists\,\alpha\in V$ such that, $T(\alpha)=x$
Therefore, $T^2(\alpha)=0\implies T^3(\alpha)=0$.
Now, from \eqref{eqn5} we have $\alpha\in$ Null space $(T)\implies T(\alpha)=0=x$
$\square$

Answer (score 0):

In general we have $\ker T\subset \ker T^3$, so the hypothesis is equivalent to
$\ker T = \ker T^3$, which is equivalent to $\ker T \supset \ker T^3$. This is equivalent to:

if $T^3 v = 0$ then $Tv = 0$, that is : if $T^2 (Tv) = 0$ then $Tv = 0$, so equivalent to
$$\ker T^2 \cap \operatorname{Im} T = (0)$$